# In Unity, why does a positive Z-axis rotation goes counter-clockwise while X and Y rotations go clockwise?

Tags: rotation

In Unity:

With a perspective having Y and Z axes pointing up and right respectively, if I make a positive X rotation, the object rotates clockwise

With a perspective having Z and X axes pointing up and right respectively, if I make a positive Y rotation, it also rotates clockwise

But Z rotation behaves differently. With a perspective having Y and X axes pointing up and right respectively, if I make a positive Z rotation, It rotates counter-clockwise, not clockwise.

Why is that?

Comment: Point your left thumb in the direction of the axis of rotation. Positive rotation will then turn in the direction that your fingers curl. This is consistent around every axis.

Comment: Have a [coordinate system chart](https://twitter.com/FreyaHolmer/status/1325556229410861056/photo/1).

Answer (score 1):

When you have Y and Z pointing up and right respectively, the rotation is *positive* and the X-axis is pointing *towards* you.

When you have Z and X pointing up and right respectively, the rotation is *positive* and the Y-axis is pointing *towards* you.

When you have Y and X pointing up and right respectively (I assumed "X and Y" is a typo), the rotation is **counter-clockwise** and the Z-axis is pointing **away from** you.

What you wrote, "X up and Y right", is equivalent to having Y pointing up and X pointing left (or, Y pointing down and X pointing right). This implies the Z-axis is now pointing **towards** you, and the rotation will occur **clockwise**.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is a typo. I have edited it.